# Is there a reason why this batch line to copy files from one drive to another only completes halfway?

Tags: batch-file, xcopy, windows-task-scheduler

Using the below line to copy all files from C drive folder 'Data' to D drive folder 'odrive DATA' and will create a new folder to store copied files.

```
echo ### Copying files from company data to odrive backup...
xcopy C:\Data D:\"odrive DATA"\%yymmdd_hhmmss%\*.* /S /Y /c
```

The batch file typically will go through half of the command each day and then just stop. Transferring a lot of data over though so not sure if this could be the case. C:\Data should have about 500GB of data only get about 300GB when done.

Any thoughts on how I should proceed here?

Comment: Try reading the error message. It's in TS.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and enter `xcopy /?` to read the usage information for the command. You'll probably note from the outset that `[<Destination>]` is supposed to specifiy the destination of the files you want to copy. _This parameter can include a drive letter and colon, a directory name, a file name, or a combination of these._ Does that help answer your question? Next time instead if wasting other people's time posting questions on the web, please read the manual first. I also hope that you've properly defined a variable named `yymmdd_hhmmss`, if not you've got more to research.

Comment: Variables are set properly; no issue with that. I'm checking the task scheduler it says the file runs properly. That's not the issue from what I can tell. All of the files will copy until I reach about 300GB or halfway through all of the folders it needs to copy then it just stops. Any ideas why it would just stop halfway? I tried to include a 'Pause' at the end to see if I could catch an error but haven't seen anything.

Comment: weslang, you can argue your case as hard as you like but if you insist that `D:\"odrive DATA"\%yymmdd_hhmmss%\*.*` or more correctly, `"D:\odrive DATA\%yymmdd_hhmmss%\*.*"` is a destination directory, you're going to struggle to find people willing to assist you further. My best guess is that you're supposed to be using `C:\Data\*.*` or `C:\Data` as the source and `"D:\odrive DATA\%yymmdd_hhmmss%\"` as the destination. You may wish to include some other options, or move to `RoboCopy` which superseded `XCopy` as long ago as Windows Vista. Have you logged what happens or checked the error codes?

Comment: Ohh I see what you're saying now. I'll try that out, thanks!

Comment: As I said first you could have read that in TS's history tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up catching the issue after turning echo on and found that it was an insufficient memory error. Changed xcopy to ROBOCOPY and got it working. Appreciate the help!